# YouTube API: API says it is embeddable and not blocked but when it is embedded it is blocked

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I wonder if anyone ever encounters this problem. I am trying to embed "The Killers - Human" Music Video.

When I did an API feed request as follow:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc&q=_Q9B9LOJIXsk

It shows that the video is embeddable and is not blocked. It even states that you can embed using the following URL:

http://www.youtube.com/v/Q9B9LOJIXsk?f=videos&app=youtube_gdata

However, when I tried this and played the video, I have received an error that the video contains content from UMG and is restricted to playback on certain sites. It is SUPPOSED to be able to playback.

I have double checked all the states etc. I wonder if I have missed anything to determine if a video is not embeddable or not on certain site.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you open the json you can actually see this

```
"status":{"value":"restricted","reason":"limitedSyndication"},
"restrictions":[{"type":"country","relationship":"deny","countries":"DE"}]
```

Comment: can we access those video_id or not ??

Comment: How do you want to access these video_ids?

Comment: those means restricted ids . Can we access by some way or not ?