# Embed youtube videos

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, embed

I want to put a video on my website using the embed option on youtube.It shows up but when i try to play it appears a text saiyng that the video is restricted on some websites and gives me the option to watch on youtube . I saw that i need to accept some terms of conditions and that includes the youtube API from what i saw . 
Is there another way to put a video on a website without the API ? Also i should mention that the website is not on a server.
I'm using this iframe to show the video :

```
 <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dgV1n57ejCY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Did you upload that video?

Comment: Maybe this can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407482/youtube-embed-gives-restricted-from-playback-on-certain-sites-error-despite-ap

Comment: @EduardValentin sometimes the uploader disable remote play.

Comment: So i need to enable that on that channel ?

Comment: I mean, the owner should enable that ?