# Video Embeddable On Some Sites But Not Others

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I'm using the YouTube API to search for videos. With my search I'm including the following parameters: type = video, videoEmbeddable = true, videoSyndicated = true. But results that I'm getting can't be played on my site still. An example call I'm doing would be

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=Yellow+Claw&maxResults=25&type=video&videoSyndicated=true&videoEmbeddable=true&videoCategoryId=10&key=

But the results still give me an error when embedding stating that

> This video contains content from ____. It is restricted from playback from certain sites or applications.

The part that really throws me off is that I've seen the exact same video embedded on another site.

Is there some sort of setting that I don't know about that needs to be changed? Is this call incorrect and is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you check this [blog](https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions_28.html), it may help you identify which part of your code need to be fix or some changes.

There were 5 specified areas that you need to check, mainly

1. [`yt:accessControl`](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#youtube_data_api_tag_yt:accessControl)
2. [Geo Restrictions](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#restrictionsp)
3. [`yt:state`](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#youtube_data_api_tag_yt:state)
4. Rentals
5. Other Restrictions not Currently Exposed via the API

Check your codes base the restriction set by the YouTube API. For further reference, check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407482/youtube-embed-gives-restricted-from-playback-on-certain-sites-error-despite-ap).