# Can't embed certain YouTube videos, iframe displays “the video contains content from SME. it is restricted from playback on certain sites” in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am working on ionic framework and I want to embed the you tube video in my application but have  problem in when I run this in mobile..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpII6.png)

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407482/youtube-embed-gives-restricted-from-playback-on-certain-sites-error-despite-ap

Answer (score 0):

I read it on youtube help forum where someone has posted the same problem and it clearly says this error is because the content is copyrighted:

the [youtube forum link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtube/ZbpiDVX-H_M/spmLVAdyDgAJ) to the message which says:

> That message is telling you that the video contains copyrighted content, used without permission of the copyright owners. Those entities (Universal Music Group, Sony Music Entertainment, and VEVO) have exercised their right of ownership to control where their property is being used, and they have blocked it from playback on mobile devices and apps. The only way around this error is to find videos that do not use unauthorized (read that as illegal) content.